# Boolean represented as text or number?

Tags: mysql, types, boolean, primitive

I am creating an application with three data types:

- Number
- Text
- Date

The app is geared towards a non-technical user who would know what a date is, or what a number is (without caring/knowing if it's an int, decimal, float, etc.). My question is, which type do you think would seem the most 'intuitive' for a user to represent a boolean value, Number or Text?

I think Number is the correct answer technically (in sql I would store it as `tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL`), but I'm not so sure if that is the easiest to understand for a non-technical user, who might think of a boolean as a "Yes" or "No" or a "True" or "False", both of which look like and sound like text.

Which data type would you classify a boolean in under these circumstances and why?

Comment: Why not boolean? And bit in sql

Comment: A boolean is a boolean. Don't discount it as a number or a text. What it's stored as in memory or on disk is a different story completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also think that technically correct to use 1 or 0. But, given that the issue arose and came here, you probably care about accessibility. And so in this case, the text "Yes" and "No" is the most accessible of all that can be.

Answer (score -1):

Of course number is easy to work with in the future. Also for non-technical user you can put some comments about definition 0 and 1

Comment: could you please elaborate?